# Powershell Regedit System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0, notifyicon, regedit

How i can modify the Notify Icons in notification Area ?

Like [PS Tray Factory](http://www.pssoftlab.com/pstf_info.phtml) and many other

They can list all actuals notifyIcon and hide selected by user.

Is an equivalent of `$myNotifyIcon.Visible = $false` in powershell, for System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon created object.

If we can create an object of this type, can we also retrieve all notifyIcons with powershell ? or other (regedit, C++/C#)

How works software like PS Tray Factory ?

I want to simply hide icons (not all) of thirds party softwares on Windows 10 devices (tablets with l-GPO, no under domain, used in travel-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

> If we can create an object of this type, can we also retrieve all notifyIcons with powershell ? or other (regedit, C++/C#)
>
> How works software like PS Tray Factory ?

Most probably by calling the Shell32 API function [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you want to do something similar from PowerShell or C#, you can find the DllImport signature (and a definition for the `NOTIFYICONDATA` struct) on the P/Invoke.NET website: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.Shell_NotifyIcon

Comment: Thanks for answered, I do not see how I could retrieve the icons of the System Tray? Do you have a track to direct me? sincerely,